# Schedule Python scripts with dependencies using Oozie

Tags: python, hadoop, workflow, cloudera, oozie

I'm working on a Cloudera environment using Oozie to schedule jobs.
Given that Oozie lets users schedule Shell scripts in Workflows, I have created the following .sh file in my Hadoop directory:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

When this .sh is scheduled in a Oozie Workflow, everything is working properly because:

- Python is found in the path mentioned in the Shebang
- `sys` is a module available

However, a .sh file like this would not work:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import pandas
```

That is because `pandas` is not available.

Is it possible to create a .sh file which bundles the required Python dependencies (maybe referring to files contained in the Hadoop directory) without having to install Python libraries in the Python environment?

Comment: You can ship an "archive" to any YARN job, and that works with Oozie too. In practice the "archive" is a ZIP file on HDFS, and YARN automatically unzips it in a sub-dir of the CWD of every job container; e.g. you can invoke included files with a relative PATH e.g. `./MyArchiveName/bin/python`

Comment: If you don't like hand-crafted solutions, you can use tools too... e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/pex-the-secret-sauce-for-the-perfect-pyspark-deployment-of-aws-emr-workloads-9aef0d8fa3a5  >> that one seeems to be used "at scale" cf. https://medium.com/criteo-labs/packaging-code-with-pex-a-pyspark-example-9057f9f144f3